# Best links to start up with Linq

Tags: linq

I would like to know when exactly we need to use Linq, Why it is used for and complete knowledge on it.

Please suggest me links/books for it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting with [LINQ 101](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b). You would find lots of examples if you just google with "LINQ".

Comment: I would also suggest using LINQPad as an easy way to write,test and practice: http://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: Agree, but to start on understanding LINQ, the link which I shared is pretty good.